# Java increase array by X size

Tags: java, vector, arraylist

I need an array that I can determine its size from the start and if it has no more empty spaces then increase its size by `X`. For example:

```
int arraySize = 2;
int[] intArray = new int[arraySize]; 
int counter = 0;

while(something){       
    if(counter == arraySize){
        // increase array size by X
    }

    intArray[counter] = counter;
    counter++;
}
```

I checked `ArrayList` and `Vector` but I did not find a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `ArrayList` is better in this case instead of simple arrays because automatically grows. From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of
>   the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at
>   least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an
>   ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth
>   policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has
>   constant amortized time cost.

But if you have to use arrays, [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) utility class comes to your aid

```
intArray = Arrays.copyOf(intArray, intArray.length + x);
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot expand an array in Java. Once it is created, its size is fixed.

With `ArrayList` this is not a problem at all, since it expands automatically to fit new elements as you `.add()` them.

If you insist on using arrays anyway, you can use that:

```
intArray = Arrays.copyOf(intArray, newLength);
```

But use `ArrayList` if you don't have a specific need for arrays. You can use `.toArray()` on it to turn it into an array as well; note however that if this is an array of integers you'll have to use an `Integer[]` -- there is unfortunately no method in the JDK which returns an `int[]` from an `Iterable<Integer>`, and that is a pity. [Guava has such a method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#toArray%28java.util.Collection%29), use Guava.

**NOTE**: don't use `Vector` if you can help it; this class is completely obsolete in new code. Some parts of the JDK still use it for compatibility reasons, but that's about it. If you need concurrency, there is much better, for instance `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Arrays.copyOf :

```
intArray = Arrays.copyOf(intArray, intArray.length + additional);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is by creating new array and copying data. However it is suggested that you use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

either use "System.arraycopy" or use ArrayList for achieving your variable size goal

Answer (score 0):

**`ArrayList` or `Vector` is resizing by itself**, so you don't need to do it manually at all. The drawback is that they use object types, not primitives. You are encouraged to use `ArrayList` as `Vector` is deprecated.

If you need automatically resizable **primitive arrays** use [Apache Commons Primitives](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-primitives/).

If you want to resize your array manually you should **allocate new array** and **copy data**  and **change reference** like this:

```
int[] array_new = new int[size_new];
System.arraycopy(array, 0, array_new, 0, array.length);
array = array_new;
```

Or use `Arrays.copy()` as other answers suggests.